# Format nested array of objects in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, format

I have the below sample array of objects

```
let arr = [{id: 1,name: 'Test',segment: 'test',subCategory: [{id: 1,name:'Test1',segment:'test1'}]}]
```

I need to format this array to the below structure

```
let newArr = [{link: 'test', name: 'Test',subCategory: [{link: 'test1',name: 'Test1'}]}]
```

How to do this in an easy step in typescript?

Comment: Can there be arbitrary many levels of nesting? Or only tow like in your example? `[{...,subCategory:[{...,subCategory:[{...,subCategory:[{...}]}]}]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Map method to achieve your desired result:

```
let arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Test', segment: 'test', subCategory: [{ id: 1, name: 
'Test1', segment: 'test1' }] }
];

let newArr = arr.map(item => {
  return {
    link: item.segment,
    name: item.name,
    subCategory: item.subCategory.map(subItem => {
      return {
        link: subItem.segment,
        name: subItem.name
      };
    })
 };
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This is the basic and generic way and I'd like to shorten it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recursive` approach to get the result. You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here as:

> Recursive approach will handle the deep nesting also

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test',
    segment: 'test',
    subCategory: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Test1',
        segment: 'test1'
    }]
}]

const formatResult = (arr) => arr.map(obj => {
    const { id, segment, subCategory, ...rest } = obj
    const subCategoryFromatted = subCategory ? formatResult(subCategory): null;
    
    return subCategoryFromatted 
            ? { ...rest, link: segment, subCategory: subCategoryFromatted }
            : { ...rest, link: segment };
})

console.log(formatResult(arr));
```